# How to make attractive button using CSS

Tags: css

Please check these screenshots. Now I want to replace background color of Log IN button of the second image by the first image.

Can anyone provide code?

My code is:

```
buttonContainer: {
  backgroundColor: '#9ce8d3';
  paddingVertical: 12;
  borderRadius: 5;
  marginTop: 25;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show some effort first ;)

Comment: We need your code, not screenshots

Comment: Already `-6`, I would recommend you edit your post and learn some **basic** CSS

Comment: I would recommend [gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), plus the right color combination

Comment: Now check it guys.

Comment: @NitinBisht it doesn't make any difference that you have made the screenshots or not. The problem is that **you have no code**. We're on stackoverflow here...

Comment: @Ivan check it. I have the code.

Comment: Yes but you don't know how to write CSS (selector is wrong, all properties names are wrong, you have a `:`, no units are being used and also have  `,` instead of `;`)

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code would be better.

But you can just use a gradient generator, with the right colors, like [this one](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

So you could have something like :

```
background: #3dbeb2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #3dbeb2 0%, #02b5d1 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3dbeb2 0%,#02b5d1 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #3dbeb2 0%,#02b5d1 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3dbeb2', endColorstr='#02b5d1',GradientType=1 );
```

Edit : Didn't see your code edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any gradient, just a simple background-color hex value.

The background color is `#32b9cd`

```css
.button {
  /* colors */
  color: white;
  background-color: #32b9cd;

  /* positioning */
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;

  /* font styling */
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* curve on borders */
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">LOG IN</div>
```